# How do I make a shell script loop through multiple if statements forever?

Tags: command-line, scripts, xdotool, syntax

I've made a shell script based on a bunch of snippets and tutorials I've read. I just can't figure out how to fix a syntax error and make it work. Terminal output is:

```
./afkscript.sh: 2 ./afkscript.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected ( expecting "done")
```

From what I read on the tutorials those brackets are needed.
Here's my script (with window name replaced):

```
while true 
do
sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 10 ) + 1 ]s
DIFF=$((46-1+1))
R=$ ( ( $ ( ($RANDOM%DIFF) ) +1) )
if [[ "R" -eq 1 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "a"
elif [[ "R" -eq 2 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type ""
elif [[ "R" -eq 3 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "d"
elif [[ "R" -eq 4 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "f"
elif [[ "R" -eq 5 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "g"
elif [[ "R" -eq 6 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "h"
elif [[ "R" -eq 7 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "j"
elif [[ "R" -eq 8 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "k"
elif [[ "R" -eq 9 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "l"
elif [[ "R" -eq 10 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type ";"
elif [[ "R" -eq 11 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "'"
elif [[ "R" -eq 12 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "\"
elif [[ "R" -eq 13 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "q"
elif [[ "R" -eq 14 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "w"
elif [[ "R" -eq 15 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "e"
elif [[ "R" -eq 16 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "r"
elif [[ "R" -eq 17 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "t"
elif [[ "R" -eq 18 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "y"
elif [[ "R" -eq 19 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "u"
elif [[ "R" -eq 20 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "i"
elif [[ "R" -eq 21 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "o"
elif [[ "R" -eq 22 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "p"
elif [[ "R" -eq 23 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "["
elif [[ "R" -eq 24 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "]"
elif [[ "R" -eq 25 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "1"
elif [[ "R" -eq 26 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "2"
elif [[ "R" -eq 27 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "3"
elif [[ "R" -eq 28 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "4"
elif [[ "R" -eq 29 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "5"
elif [[ "R" -eq 30 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "6"
elif [[ "R" -eq 31 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "7"
elif [[ "R" -eq 32 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "8"
elif [[ "R" -eq 33 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "9"
elif [[ "R" -eq 34 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "0"
elif [[ "R" -eq 35 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "-"
elif [[ "R" -eq 36 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "="
elif [[ "R" -eq 37 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "z"
elif [[ "R" -eq 38 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "x"
elif [[ "R" -eq 39 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "c"
elif [[ "R" -eq 40 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "v"
elif [[ "R" -eq 41 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "b"
elif [[ "R" -eq 42 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "n"
elif [[ "R" -eq 43 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "m"
elif [[ "R" -eq 44 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type ","
elif [[ "R" -eq 45 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "."
elif [[ "R" -eq 46 ]]; then
xdotool search --name "WINDOWNAME" windowactivate --sync
sleep .05
xdotool type "/"
else
break
fi
done
```

Comment: The syntax for bash arithmetic expression evaluation is exactly `(( expression ))` - you can't just throw in extra whitespace or parentheses i.e. `R=$(( $RANDOM%DIFF + 1 ))`  or `R=$(( RANDOM % DIFF + 1 ))` but not `R=$ ( ( $ ( ($RANDOM%DIFF) ) +1) )`

Comment: I would suggest that you start out by making small segment sampling of the full script to test and ensure you're using the right syntax.  Get that part working, then add the other parts.  Also, including a structured formatting will help to recognize visually where your loops may loose integrity.  Are you able to succeed with a 6 or 8 line segment of your full script?  If parts work and parts fail, test the syntax against the required structure provided by Steeldriver.

Comment: +1 amen to that @L.D.James  Beyond that I don't see the point of coding a massive `if . . . then` block - why not consider creating a lookup table using an associative array like `mychr=( [1]="a" [2]="" [3]="d"  . . . )` Then you can simply do `xdotool type "${mychr[$R]}"` for every case.

Answer (score 0):

Based soley on your title, an infinite `if` statement is just a `while` with the logic tweaked accordingly.

Also, your code is extremely hectic and you urgently need to use some formatting.

In addition to that you should **read your error**. It clearly states that you have an extra parantheses somewhere, so take a better look at your code and experiment to find a solution. In order to actually provide an answer, I'll tell you now that you need to move your '$' before the parentheses start. That's just how variables work.

Finally, make sure your title is relevant to your question in the future.